# Error occur while declare object with same name , but no error if we declare object use a for loop

Tags: java, list, object, dto

```
for(i=0; i< 3; i++){
            DescriptionInfoDTO description = new DescriptionInfoDTO();
            description.setLanguage("English");
            description.setName("anu");
            description.setState("Kerala");
            descriptionInfoList.add(description);
}
```

while executing , this code create 3 DescriptionInfoDTO object with 
'description' as name and add it to a list. This code execute correctly without showing any error...

But if we declare object like below, ie without using for loop, error happens, why?

```
DescriptionInfoDTO description = new DescriptionInfoDTO();
            description.setLanguage("English");
            description.setName("anu");
            description.setState("Kerala");
            descriptionInfoList.add(description);

DescriptionInfoDTO description = new DescriptionInfoDTO();
            description.setLanguage("English");
            description.setName("anu");
            description.setState("Kerala");
            descriptionInfoList.add(description);

DescriptionInfoDTO description = new DescriptionInfoDTO();
            description.setLanguage("English");
            description.setName("anu");
            description.setState("Kerala");
            descriptionInfoList.add(description);
```

is both code do same thing?

Comment: No its not same thing. in for block scope of the object is for that block only.

Comment: Because the first is only declared once and re-assigned multiple times.  There is no abiguity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the first and the second is that in first you are running a loop, i the loop all variable s you create are destroyed completion of the loop, so when you go to next iteration you can create a new variable

```
for(i=0; i< 3; i++){
            DescriptionInfoDTO description = new DescriptionInfoDTO();
            description.setLanguage("English");
            description.setName("anu");
            description.setState("Kerala");
            descriptionInfoList.add(description);
} //description is destroyed here
```

but in second case you create a new variable whereas another variable already exists in the same scope. which is not possible

Answer (score 2):

The point here is: within the for loop, the variable only exists within the boundaries (scope) of that loop, and ceases to exist once the loop finishes.

This way, the variables never exist 'at the same time'.

This makes it possible to re-declare it, just not at the same time, as you try to do it in the code without the loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the second snippet to

```
{
    DescriptionInfoDTO description = new DescriptionInfoDTO();
            description.setLanguage("English");
            description.setName("anu");
            description.setState("Kerala");
            descriptionInfoList.add(description);
}

{
    DescriptionInfoDTO description = new DescriptionInfoDTO();
            description.setLanguage("English");
            description.setName("anu");
            description.setState("Kerala");
            descriptionInfoList.add(description);
}

{
    DescriptionInfoDTO description = new DescriptionInfoDTO();
            description.setLanguage("English");
            description.setName("anu");
            description.setState("Kerala");
            descriptionInfoList.add(description);
}
```

it will be equivalent to the first snippet and will pass compilation.

Answer (score 0):

are getting an error for multiple declarations because you are *declaring multiple variables of the same name*.

If you declare a variable within a loop then it is only accessible *within the scope of that loop* meaning that as soon as the current iteration finishes, it will be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you declare the objects in scope of one loop iteration. After one iteration the object doesn't exist anymore.

In the second case you define three objects in the same scope. Wich results in a compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are *scoped* (see [JLS §6.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) for further information).

The loop body declares its own scope, so the two code snippets are *not* equivalent. They would be, if you also make these lines scoped:

```
{
    DescriptionInfoDTO description = new DescriptionInfoDTO();
    description.setLanguage("English");
    description.setName("anu");
    description.setState("Kerala");
    descriptionInfoList.add(description);
}

{
    DescriptionInfoDTO description = new DescriptionInfoDTO();
    description.setLanguage("English");
    description.setName("anu");
    description.setState("Kerala");
    descriptionInfoList.add(description);
}

{
    DescriptionInfoDTO description = new DescriptionInfoDTO();
    description.setLanguage("English");
    description.setName("anu");
    description.setState("Kerala");
    descriptionInfoList.add(description);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The lifetime of the object in the for loop will end after that iteration, but if you declare it separately like the code you have shown instead of for loop. It can't place multiple variables with same name on stack that why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

The actual difference between the two examples is the [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) in which the variable exists:

- in the first example the scope of the variable is a single iteration of the loop - a new scope is created for each iteration and everything declared inside the curly braces is local for that scope (unless it is declared outside the braces, as is the `i` variable)
- in the second example all the three variables exist in one scope and only one variable for a name is allowed in a scope